# Drawing inside Canvas Tag after set Visibility

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net

I have this code.

```
<asp:Panel id="aPanel" runat="Server">
   <canvas id="aCanvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
</asp:Panel>
```

Inside this canvas i draw lines with mouse using Javascript Code

With server-side control i set this panel visible or not when i hit a button.

When i load tha page for the first time the canvas work correctly and i can draw inside it.
When i toogle the visibility of the Panel (go to aPanel.visible = false and then to aPanel.visible = true) canvas drawing stop to work.

Any tips to fix it?

Comment: and what happend if you hide/unhide the canvas with the panel

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself badly and excuse me for my english. What you say is the behavior that i obtain when hide/unhide the panel. I try to change aPanel with a <div> but i obtain the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using aPanel.visible = false and aPanel.visible = true for hide/unhide use

```
document.getElementById('<%=aPanel.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

for hiding panel.

```
document.getElementById('<%=aPanel.ClientID %>').style.display = '';
```

for unhide panel.

you can hide/unhide panel by setting panel's style display property.